# Can this be made in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using WindowBuilder to create GUI for my app. Since I have a lot of frames inside main frame I liked idea from this app:

[image]

So when user click on button different frame (different labels and so on) is showed... Can we make this in Java?

Comment: Those are called tabs.

Comment: Can this be made in Java?  Yes.  I'm not a fan of the color selection.  There's not enough contrast for me to read the text.  It appears to be a JFrame with a JTabbedPane.  Each JPanel would be placed on a pane of the JTabbedPane.  The layout manager for each JPanel would probably be a GridBagLayout.

Comment: Why you want to do anything in Java is beyond me.

Comment: That GUI not only uses 'pornographers colors' (to quote my HTML guru friends) but also has so little contrast between the BG & tab color that they are hard to make out.  *Please* do not attempt to emulate it too closely..

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a [Swing TabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

> With the JTabbedPane class, you can have several components, such as
>   panels, share the same space. The user chooses which component to view
>   by selecting the tab corresponding to the desired component. If you
>   want similar functionality without the tab interface, you can use a
>   card layout instead of a tabbed pane.

Comment: nice that is what I needed. Thank you @Brian Agnew

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called a JTabbedPane. It is mostly a collection of JPanel(s), and you set a certain action for each of them to load a new one when clicked.

here is more information, Hope it helps!

[JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make this in Java Swing.

Look into `JLabel`, `JTabbedPane`, `JFrame`, `JPanel`, `JTextField` etc...

Those are all components you will need to create something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's called a JTabbedPane, check out this oracle tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: Urgh brain blip, don't know what came over me. Thanks for pointing that out.